# rewriting rule with dash

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Do you know why

```
RewriteRule ^register_as/commerce_([^/]*)$ /beta/register?commerce=$1 [L]
```

works and

```
RewriteRule ^register-as/commerce_([^/]*)$ /beta/register?commerce=$1 [L]
```

it doesn't?

By the way, what is the best character for SEO? ('/', '-', '_')

Thank you!

Comment: How do you know 2nd rule isn't working?

Comment: Because if I put the 2nd one, the page doesn't get the variable commerce value... :(

Comment: But what the actual URL that you try to open in browser?

Comment: I don't know if I understood your question. But if I write '.../register_as/commerce_basic' on the navbar, the page gets 'basic' value, but If I write '.../register-as/commerce_basic' the page doesn't get the 'basic' value...

Comment: Well you URL should be `http://domain.com/register-as/commerce_basic` and rule should be in `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`

Comment: Excuse me, but I don't know what 'DocumentRoot...' is or where should be... and do you think using relative paths would be the problem?

Comment: Yes it can be a problem. `DocumentRoot` is the root directory of your website.

Comment: Do you happen to have a file or directory that starts with `register-as`?

Comment: Hi friends! After trying in different ways, I've decided to replace the filename separator for '_'. I've written is better than '/' for Google and, the most important thing, rewrite works! :)